# How to connect to PostgreSQL with java?

Tags: postgresql

I want to use PostgreSQL in connection with Java. I tried using it with a normal Postgres connection but I am not able to get a connection.

I am getting the following error:

```
public Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        connection = null;
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
           "jdbc:postgresql://host:5433/postgres","username", "password");
        //"postgres://user_name:password@159.8.128.86:5433/name");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);

    }
    return connection;
    }
```

> Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at ConnectionPostgres.getConnection(ConnectionPostgres.java:25)
>
> at Client.main(Client.java:7)

Comment: You should show the java code you are using. The exception *might* mean that you fed a `null` somewhere.

Comment: can u share the complete java class that you are using to get postgresql connection?

Comment: calling `connection.close()` in the catch block is useless because if there was an exception the connection won't be established anyway. Please use `e.printStackTrace()` instead of `System.out.println(e);` then show us the complete stacktrace of the SQLException. The `java.lang.NullPointerException` is a result of calling `connection.close()`

Comment: So which is line exactly is line 25 in the above code (assuming that is `ConnectionPostgres.java`)? The code shown will not generate a NullPointerException

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Code is working fine issue was with the network connection.